# Unit test if Cors is added to the ServiceCollection

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net

I am trying to unit test if the ServiceCollection contains Cors.

```
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureCors(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
    }
}
```

Below is what I have been able to write so far,

```
[Fact]
private void Extension_ShouldSetCors()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.ConfigureCors();
    Assert.True(services.Count > 0);
}
```

Is there a better way to test it? May be get the policy name and test it?

Comment: You could always search the source code on GitHub to see how they unit tested **their** code. Not seeing a point here for wanting to unit test a 3rd party's code though.

Comment: once it is not your code it is 3rd party code, which includes the framework, that would have been tested extensively by MS before release.

Comment: @Nkosi An interesting suggestion! Seems they [start up `npm` using `cmd`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Middleware/CORS/test/FunctionalTests/CorsMiddlewareFunctionalTest.cs) and actually [run JavaScript in a browser to test](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Middleware/CORS/test/FunctionalTests/test.js) if CORS is working as expected.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that OP is interested more in some kind of smoke test to see that the CORS policies were added, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write a smoke test that relies on [how `CorsOptions` *currently* works internally](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsOptions.cs), you can write something along these lines:

```
[Fact]
public void Extension_ShouldSetCors()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.ConfigureCors();
    Assert.True(services.Count > 0);

    using (var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
    {
        var options = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IOptions<CorsOptions>>();
        Assert.NotNull(options);
        Assert.NotNull(options.Value);
        var expectedPolicy = options.Value.GetPolicy("CorsPolicy");
        Assert.True(expectedPolicy.AllowAnyOrigin);
        Assert.True(expectedPolicy.AllowAnyMethod);
        Assert.True(expectedPolicy.AllowAnyHeader);
        Assert.True(expectedPolicy.SupportsCredentials);
    }
}
```

Note that Microsoft themselves use a rather different approach, and [start up `npm` using `cmd`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Middleware/CORS/test/FunctionalTests/CorsMiddlewareFunctionalTest.cs) and actually [run JavaScript in a browser to test](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Middleware/CORS/test/FunctionalTests/test.js) if CORS is working as expected.

You could do something similar by inspecting the headers on simulated requests if you're [using ASP.NET Core's integration testing setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2), and relies less on the internals of the extension method, and better tests the thing you actually care about: headers on your responses.